# How to reduce mysql UPDATEs when viewing forum topics

Tags: php, mysql, delay, forum, accumulate

Every time a topic/thread on a forum is viewed by members, an update is done on the topic table to increase the total views by one.

I am after answers on possible ways to not do an update on every view, but to accumulate the views for each topic and 
- (how to?) add views and then do an update for the summed views periodically via cron
- (how to?) queue the updates
- other options?

Comment: do yoy realy need to store view count in topics table? create another one - with `topic, user, cnt` fields

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use of `Static variable` or `temp table` to maintain the count and later update the table in a time duration.

Comment: Thank you, I thought static variables would only last the duration of the script. As there are multiple members viewing multiple topics, not sure how this would work.

Comment: Y not? Static is `one per class`. you can store it till server restart in between you can save it to DB and initialize again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to cache the number of topic views and run an update query every X minutes via cron or check every N topic views to run a query. 
For users to see the correct number of topic/forum views return the cached value.
using APC

```
/*a small example using Topic ID and inc number*/
$TopicID=123;
if(apc_exists($TopicID)){
  echo "TotalViews : ".apc_inc($TopicID,1)."<br/>";
}else{
  // query database for numbers of views and cache that number, say its 10
 apc_store($TopicID,10);

 echo "TotalViews : ".apc_inc($TopicID,1)."<br/>";
}
/**********/
/*a larger example using a ForumIndex to hold all IDs, usefull for running a cron job and update Database*/
$ForumIndex = array(
        ("threads")=>array(
                (456) => 1000
        ),
        ("topics")=>array(
                (123)=>10
        )
);
if(apc_exists("forum_index")){ // if it exists
    $currentIndex = apc_fetch("forum_index");  // get current Index
    $currentIndex["topics"][] = array( // add a new topic 
        (1234)=>124
    );
    $currentIndex["threads"][456] += 1; // Increase threads with ID 456 by 1 view
    apc_store("forum_index",$currentIndex); // recache
    var_dump(apc_fetch("forum_index")); // view cached data
}else{ // it doesn't exists
    /*Fetch from database the value of the views */
        // Build $ForumIndex array and cache it
    apc_store("forum_index",$ForumIndex);
    var_dump(apc_fetch("forum_index"));
}
/*a cron job to run every 10 min to update stuff at database*/
if(apc_exists("forum_index")){
    $Index = apc_fetch("forum_index");
    foreach($Index as $ID => $totalViews){
        // execute update query
    }
    // delete cached data or do nothing and continue using cache
}else{
    echo "Ended cron job .. nothing to do";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to find some cache examples prior to posting the question but couldn't find any relevant to the question. Maybe incorrect key words! Each topic would need to have it's views cached, which adds to the complexity.

Comment: i don't believe its that complex, store a key with the topic/forum ID, prefixed or no(to avoid conflicts), and assign the value of views to it, also not the entire forum/topics ids will be stored in cache only those who topics/threads/forums that are often visited except if you forum/topics are accessed by thousands/millions of users in a period of 10minutes..
Added some small examples using APC, hope it helped

Comment: Thank you GeoPhoenix, I'd vote you up but my low level rep won't allow it. I'm currently using eaccelerator so might be time to switch to APC.